# why controller methods are processed sequentially in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, browser

I've the following controller *Home*:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void Index()
    {
        Response.Write($"{DateTime.Now}  begin <br>");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Response.Write($"{DateTime.Now}  end <br>");  
    }
```

when i open ~/Home/Index with browser in two tabs , i see that request is processed sequentially. **Session disabled.** How to make browser to process request concurrently ?

Comment: I can confirm this. Initially I tested with Postman, it seemed running concurrently instead of one by one. But then I tried with Chrome and Edge, it ran one by one as you can tell from the responses, they were not overlap no matter how quick you execute another request before the previous one completed. I even tried running multiple requests with Chrome and Edge at the same time, they were executed one after the other. It is concurrently between Postman and browser(s) but not between browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, I guess the browser may thought the requests are the same and would like to checks if the response can be cached before sending the second request.

To run it concurrently, one simple way is to append fake parameter to the url to make them different every time, for example, 
/Home/Index?p=1
/Home/Index?p=2